# Synonym for "Class" in java language not in English language?

Tags: java

Whenever we talk about objects we have instances, methods : functions : behavior, member variable: state, like so many interchangeable words. but for "Class" till now i didnt see people who have used some other word. So is there any other word in java which can be used(or in use)(dont tell any English synonym) which i can use. while explaining my code.

EDIT: Dont invent looking at this question it should be in use which i might not know

Comment: Why would you like to do that? Class is quite specific and therefore clear. And you should probably not mix up methods and functions when you explain your code, it is not really the same.

Comment: I dont want to do anything with that. and i know that "class" is "the" best suited name for it. just wanted to know is there other which can be legitimately used for this. that's it.

Comment: didnt quite get your question? is java the language you are going to use when you explain your code? a little weird...

Comment: When you are talking about programming code or program design, there is no synonym. However in ordinary speech you could use category, concept or abstraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of class is related to 'universal' and all that logic (abstraction/universal against instantiation/particular) comes from Aristotle (derived from Plato) philosophy. The OOP seems to take concepts from that filosophy. 
The question for me is very relevant. Here is a link from wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotle#Universals_and_particulars), and if you read this resume you could understand the relations between Aristotle philosophy and OOP.

> Aristotle disagreed with Plato on this point, arguing that all universals are instantiated. Aristotle argued that there are no universals that are unattached to existing things. According to Aristotle, if a universal exists, either as a particular or a relation, then there must have been, must be currently, or must be in the future, something on which the universal can be predicated. Consequently, according to Aristotle, if it is not the case that some universal can be predicated to an object that exists at some period of time, then it does not exist.

Cool ah?

I hope it helps...

Comment: Yes, or to put it briefly: Java and Smalltalk are Platonic, JavaScript and Self are Aristotelian.

Comment: +1 for another explanation of why there's no final abstract classes in java :)

Comment: @Mauricio, wouldn't that mean that Java is Aristotelian?  My head hurts now.

Answer (score 3):

Instances, methods, functions, behaviour, etc., are all English words, so I don't quite comprehend your restriction.

So, for Class: Type.

Comment: `int`, `long`, `char`.  Those are not classes, but they are types.

Comment: @jjnguy : int, long, char ... are "primitive" types in Java ... in pure object (Smalltalk, Eiffel, ...) they will be considered as type and and of course classes ... +1 @Noel in oo paradigm a class = type

Comment: I agree with jjnguy, and don't forget `interface`, which also describes a type.  Class is a more specific term.

Comment: Java interfaces are not types, they only imply type in imparting aspects; qualities and characteristics. Which is why Classes "implement" interfaces.  The "Class" is the archetypical type in the OO paradigm.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, those all have slightly different meanings:  A **method** is a **function** attached to a class (they are often incorrectly used interchangably), while **behaviour** refers at a higher level to what a function/method does.

**State** refers to the specific value of a **variable**, or of many variables combined.

To answer your question, another word for *class* would be *object*, as you said yourself.

---

**[Edit]** It appears I spoke too tongue-in-cheek.  As many people have pointed out, *'object'* can also refer to an instance of a class.  I think your safest bet would be to use *class* when you mean a `class`, *instance* when you mean an `instance`, *spade* a `spade` etc.

Comment: Interesting that you make the subtle distinction between method and function, but fail to note that Objects aren't exactly Classes either.  A class is more of a blueprint of an object.

Comment: an object can be a class but it can be anything else e.g. an instance of a class

Comment: `Object` are instances of a `class`.  They are not synonyms.

Comment: -1 To use class when you mean object or vice versa I view a deep mistake, and I think the source of a great deal of confusion in some discussions.

Comment: @lucas: I would say a class is more of a blueprint of an object instance, but *'object'* is ambiguous enough to refer to either of those things

Comment: In Java, `class` is a keyword, `Object` is a class, `Class` is another class derived from `Object`, and hence (as derivation results in an "is a" relationship) `Class` is an `Object`. I hope this has clarified the matter once and for all!

Comment: to elaborate on this, "instance" doesn't mean the same thing as "object" either.

Answer (score 2):

Well I heard people referring to it as a *blueprint* (meaning that it is a definition of what kind of state and what operations an instance will provide).

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that `class` is the best way to describe a class in Java.

It is a pretty specific idea, and any synonym will not be able to capture the full meaning of the word.

Comment: @jjnguy: the word class has sense only if you are familiar with oop ... when I taught java, beginners students only get it if I compare it to a mould or a blueprint ... but semantically I think type is the best description ...

Answer (score 1):

I saw many times the word `Clazz` used in the code to avoid the reserved word. Does that help?

Comment: That's possibly a good answer to an unclear question! What's up with you people downvoting him?

Comment: Thanks nalpy... anyway I think gurukulki was looking for another type of answer :) nevermind...

Answer (score 1):

[Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype)?

Comment: That invites confusion since prototypes are distinct from classes in object-oriented programming (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming).

Comment: I don't think he's looking for an exact definition. class is the exact definition. I think he wants a more human explanation of the concept even at the cost of losing some Java language particularities.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "Mould" to describe the role of a class

Answer (score 1):

Refer to SoloLearn on google playstore.

Class is also known as Object Factory.

But FYKI, only "class" keyword is used to create a class.

Good luck